# How can I compare values in a dataframe row and select one of them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to use **Pandas** to create a new column in a dataframe in which it compares 2 columns in a row in the df, if the values are different to choose an specific column, if the values are equal to chose any of them, if one of them in NaN, to choose the other one (if both are NaN it will already be cover). I was using **Numpy** *select* and **Pandas**  *where*, but can't make it work, and I don't want to use (yet) a **for** cycle.

If i got this dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], [np.nan, "A"], ["B", np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan], ["E", "E"]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
df1
  col1 col2
0    A    B
1    C    D
2  NaN    A
3    B  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5    E    E
```

I want that the behavior is like this:

- In row 0 because (A != B) & (A != np.nan) & (B != np.nan) I want to choose the value from col1.
- In row 1 because (C != D) & (C != np.nan) & (D != np.nan) I want to choose the value from col1 (same as before).
- In row 2 because (NaN != A) & (A != np.nan) & (NaN == np.nan) I want to choose the value from col 2.
- In row 3 because (B != NaN) & (NaN == np.nan) & (B != np.nan) I want to choose the value from col 1.
- In row 4 because (NaN == NaN) & (NaN == np.nan) & (NaN == np.nan) I want to choose the value from col1 (either would work actually).
- In row 5 because (E == E) & (E != np.nan) & (E != np.nan) I want to choose the value form col 1 (same as before).

In this case I should obtain something like:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    B    A
1    C    D    C
2  NaN    A    A
3    B  NaN    B
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5    E    E    E
```

To achieve this I was doing this with `np.select`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], [np.nan, "A"], ["B", np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan], ["E", "E"]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
conditions = [
    ((df['col1'] == df['col2']) & (df['col1'] != np.nan)),
    ((df['col1'] == df['col2']) & (df['col1'] == np.nan)),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'] != np.nan) & (df['col2'] == np.nan)),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'] == np.nan) & (df['col2'] != np.nan)),
]
choices = [df['col1'], np.nan, df['col1'], df['col2']]
df['condition'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default="WHAT?")
print(df)
```

But the result is:

```
  col1 col2 condition
0    A    B     WHAT?
1    C    D     WHAT?
2  NaN    A     WHAT?
3    B  NaN     WHAT?
4  NaN  NaN     WHAT?
5    E    E         E
```

So, I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

**SEMI-EDIT**: While writing this I noticed that I was missing a case in choices, so I updated the code to this:

Hope someone can help me, thanks

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], [np.nan, "A"], ["B", np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan], ["E", "E"]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
conditions = [
    ((df['col1'] == df['col2']) & (df['col1'] != np.nan)),
    ((df['col1'] == df['col2']) & (df['col1'] == np.nan)),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'] != np.nan) & (df['col2'] == np.nan)),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'] == np.nan) & (df['col2'] != np.nan)),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'] != np.nan) & (df['col2'] != np.nan)),

]
choices = [df['col1'], np.nan, df['col1'], df['col2'], df["col1"]]
df['condition'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default="WHAT?")
print(df)
```

The result was this one:

```
  col1 col2 condition
0    A    B         A
1    C    D         C
2  NaN    A       NaN
3    B  NaN         B
4  NaN  NaN       NaN
5    E    E         E
```

To ilustrate a little bit more, I change choices to: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. This is the result:

```
  col1 col2 condition
0    A    B         5
1    C    D         5
2  NaN    A         5
3    B  NaN         5
4  NaN  NaN         5
5    E    E         1
```

It always enters in the fifth case, which is ok for row 0 and 1, but row 2 should enter case 4, row 3 should enter case 3, and row 4 should enter case 2. Row 5 is  correct with case 1.

Hope I made my self clear, thanks.

**EDIT**: someone commented and then delete something that worked for me. This person pointed out that if you do this: `print(np.nan == np.nan)` it will return `False`, so my logic will always fail. Therefore, I must user `notnull()` and `isna()` in the conditionals.

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that. Using `notnull()` and `isna()` I was able to obtain the output I wanted. Thanks for your help. If you submit a message I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.nan != np.nan` NaNs are never equal to each other so your logic is not doing what you think it is: `df['col1'] != np.nan`. Trying doing `print(np.nan == np.nan)` and it will always return False. You want to use `df['col1'].isna()` to find null values and `df['col1'].notnull()` to find non-null values.

```
conditions = [
    ((df['col1'] == df['col2']) & (df['col1'].notnull())),
    ((df['col1'] == df['col2']) & (df['col1'].isna())),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'].notnull()) & (df['col2'].isna())),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'].isna()) & (df['col2'].notnull())),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df.notnull().all(1))),# not sure if this is the logic you actually want

]
choices = [df['col1'], np.nan, df['col1'], df['col2'], df["col1"]]
df['condition'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default="WHAT?")

  col1 col2 condition
0    A    B         A
1    C    D         C
2  NaN    A         A
3    B  NaN         B
4  NaN  NaN     WHAT?
5    E    E         E
```

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem, I edited the main post because you deleted the comment. This works, but you have to change case 2 condition to `!=` because otherwise it will never enter there because np.nan != np.nan and add the condition to column 2. That condition will be something like: `((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'].isna()) & (df['col2'].isna())),`

Comment: I have to check whats does the `all(1)` do, but I believe this can work:
`conditions = [
    ((df['col1'] == df['col2'])),
    ((df['col1'].isna()) & (df['col2'].isna())),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'].notnull()) & (df['col2'].isna())),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'].isna()) & (df['col2'].notnull())),
    ((df['col1'] != df['col2']) & (df['col1'].notnull()) & (df['col2'].notnull())),
]`

Comment: `df.notnull().all(1)` just checks if all the cells in all the columns in `df` are not null across axis 1 - rowwise. So all the cells in row 1, 2, 3, . . . N are not null across all the columns. Your sample frame only has two columns so it is the equivalent of `df['col1'].notnull()) & (df['col2'].notnull()))` assuming your actual frame only has two columns. If it does not then you can also do `df[['col1', 'col2']].notnull().all(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to your problem:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], [np.nan, "A"], ["B", np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan], ["E", "E"]], columns=["col1", "col2"])

col3 = []
for i, row in df1.notna().iterrows():  
    if row.all():
        col3.append(df1['col1'].iloc[i])
    elif row.values[0]:
        col3.append(df1['col1'].iloc[i])
    else:
        col3.append(df1['col2'].iloc[i])
        
df1['col3'] = col3

print(df1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    B    A
1    C    D    C
2  NaN    A    A
3    B  NaN    B
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5    E    E    E
```

Answer (score 1):

This is would be the one that I would personally use. It is a very succinct answer using list comprehension.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], [np.nan, "A"], ["B", np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan], ["E", "E"]], columns=["col1", "col2"])

df1['col3'] = [row[0] if row[0] is not np.nan else row[1] for i, row in df1.iterrows()]

print(df1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    B    A
1    C    D    C
2  NaN    A    A
3    B  NaN    B
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5    E    E    E
```